# WP8 Server Not Found Error

Tags: json, post, windows-phone-8, webclient

I am trying to POST JSON data to my WCF service but I get a Not Found error.

Code:

```
    public void ReportSighting()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://demo.notifysolutions.com/MobileService.svc/ReportSighting", UriKind.Absolute);

        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = jsonData.Length.ToString();
        webClient.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", jsonData);
        webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(ReportSightingCompleted);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
    }

    private void PostCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Error:
InnerException = {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Syst...

I have tried this in Fiddler and it works fine.

Comment: There could be a number of problems here. The irritating problem with this version of Silverlight is that it will respond with what looks like a 404 to EVERY conceivable problem with the remote call. Let me start with the obvious stuff first. Are you connecting to your service over SSL?

Comment: I don't think I am. However, I am able to call a different method in the WCF service perfectly fine. So i'm not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you, but I'd recommend you attach Fiddler to determine what the difficulty is. This isn't as straightforward when working with an emulator, so follow [the procedure here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/10/15/fiddler-and-the-windows-phone-emulator.aspx) to get set up. Also, if the traffic is over HTTPS then you'll need to install the Fiddler root certificate on your emulator before you can decrypt SSL traffic.

Comment: I have a static IP in the office and I think it won't work using Fiddler. Would you know a way round?